# Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `a'

Tags: haskell, printing, tree

***I've never seen this concrete question before in Stackoverflow and other questions didn't help me (I've tried before open this ask).***

When I try to print a Binary Tree following this way:

```
data BinTree a = ET | Branch (BinTree a) a (BinTree a) deriving Show

ejC:: BinTree a -> String
ejC ET = ""
ejC (Branch x y z) = (ejC x) ++ "|-" ++ y ++ "-|" ++ (ejC z)
```

The module gives this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `a'
`a' is a rigid type variable bound by
the type signature for ejC :: BinTree a -> String at Types2.hs:24:7
Relevant bindings include
z :: BinTree a (bound at Types2.hs:26:17)
y :: a (bound at Types2.hs:26:15)
x :: BinTree a (bound at Types2.hs:26:13)
ejC :: BinTree a -> String (bound at Types2.hs:25:1)
In the first argument of `(++)', namely `y'
In the second argument of `(++)', namely `y ++ "-|" ++ (ejC z)'
```

Thank you all.

Comment: `(ejC x) ++ "|-" ++ y ++ "-|" ++ (ejC z)` should be `(ejC x) ++ "|-" ++ show y ++ "-|" ++ (ejC z)`

Comment: Your solution worked. So so so so and so thankful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GHC is telling you an awful lot here. It seems to be saying something about `y`, right? And about `(++)`? So, what are the types of those things?

```
y :: a
(++) :: [t] -> [t] -> [t]
```

Well, since `y` is an argument to `(++)` it must be the case that `a` is the same type as `[t]`. And since `("-|" ++ (ejC z))`, a String, is the other argument to `(++)`, that type must be String:

```
a ~ [t] ~ String
```

But your type signature says it works for any type `a` at all, not just String. Hence the error.

You could fix this a couple ways. You could change your type signature to restrict `a` to be String:

```
ejC:: BinTree String -> String
ejC = -- ...
```

It won't work on any type of tree, just String trees, but maybe that's what you wanted.

Or, you could try to turn the `a` values in the tree into Strings somehow. There's one common way to turn a thing into a String, which is by using the `show` function, but it requires that the type have an instance of Show. So, add that constraint to your function signature, and call `show` in the function's body:

```
ejC:: Show a => BinTree a -> String
ejC ET = ""
ejC (Branch x y z) = (ejC x) ++ "|-" ++ show y ++ "-|" ++ (ejC z)
```